# Get value of multiselect box using jQuery or pure JS and display on input text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the value of the multi-select box using jQuery or pure JS and display it on an input text.

I am getting value using `var value = $(this).val();` and assign the value get to variable **Round 1** i.e `var result = "round 1";` so as to display in array like in a input text like this `Round 1, Round 2, ...`.

Note: I want values of select option tag to remain numeric e.i value="90".

```js
$("select[name='no_of_rounds']").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value == "90") {
    var result = "round 1";
  } else if (value == "100") {
    var result = "round 2";
  } else if (value == "110") {
    var result = "round 3";
  } else if (value == "120") {
    var result = "round 4";
  } else if (value == "130") {
    var result = "round 5";
  }
  $("input#optionOutput").val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" name="no_of_rounds" multiple id="no_of_rounds">
  <option value="90">Round 1</option>
  <option value="100">Round 2</option>
  <option value="110">Round 3</option>
  <option value="120">Round 4</option>
  <option value="130">Round 5</option>
  <option value="140">Round 6</option>
  <option value="150">Round 7</option>
  <option value="160">Round 8</option>
  <option value="880">Round 1 - Round 8</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="optionOutput">
```

So far, I am getting only one attribute i.e. round 1, on select multiple

Comment: In jQuery, the value of a multi-select is an array of all the selected values.

Comment: What is your expected result when multiple options are selected?

Comment: @Barmar, the output I am expecting is **Round 1, Round 2,** on `id="optionOutput"`  and so on. That is when one multi-select option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is already in array form, just join() it after mapping it to the `option.text()`.

```js
$("select[name='no_of_rounds']").change(function(){
    let v = $(this).val().map(n => $(this).find(`option[value="${n}"]`).text());
    $('#optionOutput').val(v.join(", "));
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" name="no_of_rounds" multiple id="no_of_rounds">
    <option value="90">Round 1</option>
    <option value="100">Round 2</option>
    <option value="110">Round 3</option>
    <option value="120">Round 4</option>
    <option value="130">Round 5</option>
    <option value="140">Round 6</option>
    <option value="150">Round 7</option>
    <option value="160">Round 8</option>
    <option value="880">Round 1 - Round 8</option>
</select>   


<input type="text" id="optionOutput">
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is an array. You can use `.map()` to loop through it and return an array of all the values you want to put into the input field.

```js
$("select[name='no_of_rounds']").change(function() {
  var result = $(this).val().map(value => {
    if (value == "90") {
      return "round 1";
    } else if (value == "100") {
      return "round 2";
    } else if (value == "110") {
      return "round 3";
    } else if (value == "120") {
      return "round 4";
    } else if (value == "130") {
      return "round 5";
    }
  }).join(", ");
  $("input#optionOutput").val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" name="no_of_rounds" multiple id="no_of_rounds">
  <option value="90">Round 1</option>
  <option value="100">Round 2</option>
  <option value="110">Round 3</option>
  <option value="120">Round 4</option>
  <option value="130">Round 5</option>
  <option value="140">Round 6</option>
  <option value="150">Round 7</option>
  <option value="160">Round 8</option>
  <option value="880">Round 1 - Round 8</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="optionOutput">
```